# Error while defining constraints in user defined table in t-sql

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-types

I am trying to create a user defined table type where I want to define a foreign key and unique key constraints but I'm unable to do so. Whenever I run the following I got the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'."
Please someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

```
create Type firstType as Table
(
    firstId int IDENTITY (1,1)CONSTRAINT PK_firstId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (firstId),
    f_email varchar(200) CONSTRAINT AK_email UNIQUE(f_email) ,
    fname varchar(100),
    outId int CONSTRAINT FK_First FOREIGN KEY (outId) REFERENCES New(newId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Foreign Key constraints aren't supported. *"Supported constraints include PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, and CHECK. For more information about tables, see CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)."*

Comment: Incorrect syntax usually means you forgot commas somewhere. I think you have to add a comma before your constraint keyword.

Comment: The syntax isn't supported for table types, @LittleSoap , that's why they are getting a syntax error; it *is* invalid syntax for the object type.

Comment: Why are you trying to create all of this in a `TYPE` rather than a persistent table?  Here's the syntax for a `TYPE` ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table type cannot have named constraints and cannot have foreign keys.
It may have only unnamed primary keys, unique keys and check constraints.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for details.

You can use this instead:

```
CREATE Type firstType as Table
(
    firstId int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (firstId),
    f_email varchar(200) UNIQUE(f_email) ,
    fname varchar(100),
    outId int
)
```